# Is there a poisson variant for cohen's D/ Hedges' G?

Tags: distributions, effect-size

I've got a problem with some count data of mine.

I am using a cohen's D/ Hedges G to compare the effect size between two different treatment groups in my experiment, and then repeating that process for a different strain of fly with the same treatment, and comparing effect sizes for the two different groups to see if effect of treatment varies by strain.

However the actual data I get out at the end is count data in a poisson distribution, not a normal distribution.

Is there an effect size coefficient that is designed for poisson distribution, or should I just stick to these ones and take it with a pinch of salt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effect sizes only compare means (or whatever, like $\eta^2$). They make no assumptions about distributions. So they are applicable regardless of the conditional distribution.

Of course, their *interpretation* hangs on whether the means are the only thing we are interested in. Some events may have a tiny probability but a huge impact if they do occur, so the mean is very small, but in such a case, we should also be concerned about the variance.

Comment: A bit of counterpoint: because an effect size is traditionally defined using a standard deviation as the reference unit, the concept implicitly *does* make a (mild, nonparametric) distributional assumption: namely, that the SD is suited to this purpose.  As the distribution grows further from Normal--particularly as it becomes more skewed--that assumption is worth questioning, as the OP indicates.

Comment: @whuber: yes, I agree. I tried to convey this in my second paragraph.

Comment: I didn't get that message from your paragraph because "concerned about the variance" could mean many things.